# VIM+ctags+omnicppcomplete

Tags: c++, c, vim, ctags, omnicppcomplete

I am linux newbie, but I finally decided to try one, I recently installed openSUSE. On windows 7 I used Visual Studio for c/c++ programming. I tried to find any IDE under linux, tried KDevelop but didn't like it, so i decided to try to setup VIM to be my source code editor.

Firstly I needed to find some auto completion. I read some things about GCCSense and clang_complete but for now installing those things is a bit complicated for me, so I settled for omnicpp and ctags.

I downloaded omnicpp and put those files in ~/.vim folder, I installed ctags. My .vimrc looks like this:

```
set number

" --- OmniCppComplete ---  
" -- required --  
set nocp " non vi compatible mode
filetype plugin on " enable plugins

" -- optional --
" auto close options when exiting insert mode
autocmd InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|pclose|endif
set completeopt=menu,menuone

" -- configs --
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteDot = 1 " autocomplete with .
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteArrow = 1 " autocomplete with ->
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteScope = 1 " autocomplete with ::
let OmniCpp_SelectFirstItem = 2 " select first item (but don't insert)
let OmniCpp_NamespaceSearch = 2 " search namespaces in this and included files
let OmniCpp_ShowPrototypeInAbbr = 1 " show function prototype (i.e. parameters) in popup window

" -- ctags --
" map F8 to generate ctags for current folder:
map <F8> :!/usr/bin/ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<CR>
" add current directory's generated tags file to available tags

set tags=./tags,tags,/home/andrzej/vim/commontags
```

So to try it I made simple .c file

```
struct str
{
    int aaa;
};

int main()
{
    str *wsk;
    wsk->aaa=5;
    return 0;
}
```

I press F8 when I am not in input mode, it should generate tag file in place when .c file is located (map  :!/usr/bin/ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .) but no such file is generated. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Actually I think `clang_complete` is easier way, yet it also provides better result.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

Neither vim nor gvim change the current directory for you by default. Therefore, commands will be executed in the current working directory of your environment. In short, if you ran:

```
cd / && vi ~/prog/c/file.c
```

you would have the same "problem" with vi that you're having in gvim. That's why I used absolute paths in the binding I showed in my comment. Using autochdir is a reasonable solution, if that's the behavior you're expecting.

**Original:**

The problem seems to be the `+` characters. I'd suggest placing your ctags arguments into `~/.ctags`:

```
$ echo -e "--c++-kinds=+p\n--fields=+iaS\n--extras=+q" > ~/.ctags
$ cat ~/.ctags
--c++-kinds=+p
--fields=+iaS
--extra=+q
```

Then change your mapping to:

```
map <F8> :!/usr/bin/ctags -R<CR>
```

Otherwise, you can escape the '+' characters:

```
map <F8> :!/usr/bin/ctags -R --c\+\+-kinds=\+p --fields=\+iaS --extra=\+q .<CR>
```

Comment: Nothing changed, no tags file was created when I pressed F8, but when I entered this folder manually and I used ctags, tags file was created, maybe it is some VIM problem?

Comment: What exactly happens when you press `F8`? Are you sure you're in the right directory? Honestly, I'm only working on one project right now, so I just use `map <F9> :!ctags -f ~/prj/tags -R ~/prj<CR>`, so that I can run it from anywhere.

Comment: It's also possible that `F8` is conflicting with another vim binding, or one from your window manager or terminal. You could try binding to `;c` using `nmap <silent> ;c :!/usr/bin/ctags -R<CR>`.

Comment: As i wrote, the problem was with GVIM I think, because it always showed me (using :!pwd) the same directory all the time,I added autochdir and it seems to work ok (but w/o autochdir in terminal VIM everything was working). Why?

Comment: You were probably changing to the directory of the C file before opening it in vim, therefore it worked. In gvim, your directory is not the same as that of the C file, so it fails.

Answer (score 0):

**Omni**:

Anyone seen or referenced this?

https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/utils/vim/vimrc

**Tags**:

Shot from the hip (Read: untested and unverified) Try CD'ing to the current dir.

```
map <F8> :cd %:p:h <Bar> :!/usr/bin/ctags -R --c\+\+-kinds=\+p --fields=\+iaS --extra=\+q .<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for all your answers, I found where the source of the problem is. When I run VIM from terminal F8 works fine, when I type !pwd it shows the directory where my .c file is (ex. ~/prog/C), but when I use GvIM and I open the same .c file and type !pwd it shows ~/dokumenty, so I think the problem lies somewhere in VIM/GVIM. I wonder why GVIM doesen't recognize the folder, no matter what file I open?

---edit---
I added set autochdir to my .vimrc and now everything works fine, the problem is solved, but I would be grateful if someone could answer me, why everything was working when i run VIM from terminal(even when autochdir was turned off) but it didn't work for GVIM.